# Qiskit - MissingOptionalLibraryError pdflatex library is required to use LaTeX circuit drawing

Tags: qiskit, programming

Trying to run below snippet to generate circuit diagram in a `Jupyter notebook` on Windows.

```
import qiskit
qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.x(0)
qc.draw('latex')
```

I have install the [texlive for windows](https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67540032/1176573). Although, this still throws below error trace:

```
MissingOptionalLibraryError               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(1)
      3 qc.x(0)
----> 4 qc.draw('latex')
...
MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'pdflatex' library is required to use 'LaTeX circuit drawing'.  You will likely need to install a full LaTeX distribution for your system."
```

Anything missing?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the executable `pdflatex` is not in path. You might need to restart your Windows or extend the `PATH` variable with the `pdflatex` directory.